# VWP - Can I leave the US and go to Paris and return back to the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, france, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm going to be traveling to the United States to visit family. I will come back to France at my 90 days and would like to turn around and come back to the US a few days later to spend more time with my family. Will I be granted another 90 day Visa?

Comment: Although a slightly different question, I'd suggest reading http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11654/984  The short answer is that I would suspect it's highly likely you will be refused entry into the US on your second trip.

Answer (score 5):

One should separate what's legal and what's real.  Legally you should have no problem doing this and you should be able to obtain travel authorization under [ESTA](http://www.cbp.gov/xp/cgov/travel/id_visa/esta/) and re-enter the country as long as that's approved which is most likely it will be.

Problem comes if your stays in the US will start exceeding 6 months out of a year or you will be leaving and entering US after short stays abroad (Canada, Mexico, and Caribbean excluded) in this case you will likely be flagged as potentially exceeding your visa "parameters" in which case your ESTA may be denied or you could be [turned around at an airport](http://franceinsandiego.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/does-an-approved-esta-travel-authorization-guarantee-entry-into-america/).

Comment: Can you give a reference to anything official around "6 months"?  I'm fairly sure there is no reference to a 6 month period in any of the VWP rules.

Comment: @Doc It's not in the rules.  It's been related to me as an unofficial policy by an immigration lawyer.  Plus a person who was here on a B2 for 4 months left for a week and came back was told that they will likely not be able to re-enter again after such a short period away.

Answer (score 1):

You are not granted a visa anyways, you are allowed to stay for a period of time, entering with an ESTA, it's 90 days.

And as https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/61835/4188 per CBP the "rule of thumb" is you should be out for 91 days after a 90 days stay. Note this is not a law just a rule of thumb.